# Reading a stream in Ruby and extracting lines based on key words

Tags: ruby, file

I want to scan a stream and retrieve only those lines that contain a keyword, here's what I've got so far...

```
ERROR_WORDS = ['Error','Invalid','Out of Range']

error_stream = stderr.read
errors = nil
unless error_stream.nil?
   errors = ERROR_WORDS.detect{ |e| error_stream.include? e }
```

Assuming `error_stream` contains this...

```
4/19/12 - 9:00am: Last check, status ok
4/19/12 - 9:15am: File # 456 received contained Error
4/19/12 - 9:30am: Last check, status ok
4/19/12 - 9:45am: File # 457 is has an Invalid timestamp
```

...I want to scan the stream and return into `errors` only those lines (in full) that have any of the keywords in `ERROR_WORDS`, so, in this case, only lines 2 and 4 contain error words

I need `errors`, which, on second thought, probably needs to be an array, to have...

```
4/19/12 - 9:15am: File # 456 received contained Error
4/19/12 - 9:45am: File # 457 is has an Invalid timestamp
```

My code returns this...

```
Error
Invalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you read the input as lines in the first place, instead of one big string.

You have a couple different options for doing the test.  You can loop through the ERROR_WORDS array every time, but it would probably be more efficient to build a regular expression instead:

```
ERROR_REGEXP = Regexp.new(ERROR_WORDS.join '|')
```

Then your code looks like this:

```
error_lines = stderr.readlines
errors = error_lines.find_all { |line| line =~ ERROR_REGEXP }
```

If you still need the whole error stream as one big string, you can build it:

```
error_stream = error_lines.join "\n"
```

On the other hand, if you only need the lines that match, you can do the whole thing at once:

```
errors = stderr.readlines.find_all { |line| line =~ ERROR_REGEXP }
```